# Using Params in function like this C# is it a good practice

Tags: c#, .net, linq, if-statement

FUNCTION **

```
private void GetComboxItems(params int[] type) 
        {   
            try
            {
                /* DEPARTMENT CODE */
                if (type[0] == 1)
                {
                    cmbDept.Items.Clear();
                    using (SFCDataContext SFC = new SFCDataContext())
                    {
                        var Dept = (from i in SFC.Systems_SettingsDepartments
                                    orderby i.Department_ID
                                    select i);

                        foreach (var q in Dept)
                        {
                            cmbDept.Items.Add(q.Department_ID);
                        }

                        SFC.Connection.Close();
                    }                    
                }
                /* CORRECTIVE ACTION RECORD CODE */
                if (type[1] == 1)
                {
                    cmbCARNo.Items.Clear();
                    using (SFCDataContext SFC = new SFCDataContext())
                    {
                        var CarNo = (from i in SFC.Systems_CARLogSheets
                                     orderby i.CARDocNo
                                     where i.PostStatus == 0
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         Code = i.CARDocNo
                                     });
                        foreach (var w in CarNo)
                        {
                            cmbCARNo.Items.Add(w.Code);
                        }

                        SFC.Connection.Close();
                    }
                }
                /* MEASUREMENT CODE */
                if (type[2] == 1)
                {
                    cmbMeas.Items.Clear();
                    using (SFCDataContext SFC = new SFCDataContext())
                    {

                        var Measure = (from i in SFC.Systems_SettingsMeasurements
                                       orderby i.Measurement_ID
                                       where i.CategoryType == "Measurement"
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           DESC = i.Measurement
                                       });
                        foreach (var e in Measure)
                        {
                            cmbMeas.Items.Add(e.DESC);
                        }
                        SFC.Connection.Close();
                    }
                }
                /* SUB-MEASUREMENT CODE */
                if (type[3] == 1)
                {
                    cmbSubMeas.Items.Clear();
                    using (SFCDataContext SFC = new SFCDataContext())
                    {
                        var SubMeas = (from i in SFC.Systems_SettingsMeasurements
                                       orderby i.Measurement_ID
                                       where i.CategoryType == "Sub-Measurement"
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           DESC = i.Measurement
                                       });
                        foreach (var r in SubMeas)
                        {
                            cmbSubMeas.Items.Add(r.DESC);
                        }
                        SFC.Connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); }
        }
```

*** FORM LOAD ****

```
private void frmSQMProductivityReports_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetComboxItems(1, 0, 1, 0);
        }
```

why is it that at this code.. my 1st if statement is "True" so it does what follows the code inside the if statement and it does. now the 2nd if statement is "False" which it skips the function inside it. but then now the 3rd if statement is "True" which is it should have do same as the 1st but as i have checked couple times it skips the function inside the if statement why is it? is there something wrong in my codes i tried looking at it its seems ok to me..

Comment: Good heavens.  Why isn't this method `params` when you know you're always passing in four parameters??  And why are you passing in `int`s as flags instead of `bool`s?!?

Comment: This is not at all good idea...pass seperate parametres

Answer (score 1):

According to your input, the `if` conditions that meets the criteria are the first and the third.. note that some statements can be "skipped" if an exception is throw, so placing breakpoints there or printing logs may help you understand better what is happening.

Side notes:

1. The use of `params` seems to be redundant in this case (it's mostly used when an unknown #arguments should be passed) since the number of arguments is fixed.
2. use `bool` type rather then int for flags

Comment: This could also be a candidate for using `enum` Flags http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx